# Question - Trigger JS in HTML using (Hypertext link or Button)

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code with short CSS and JS to collapse some section

Code:

HTML JS Click Hypertext or Button to trigger

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
```

```css
.collapsible {
      background-color: #777;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    
    .active, .collapsible:hover {
      background-color: #555;
    }
    
    .collapsible:after {
      content: '\002B';
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .active:after {
      content: "\2212";
    }
    
    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

```html
    <p>------------------------------------------------</p>
    
    
      <a href="#about">METHOD 1 - Expand/Unexpand All -/+</a>
    
    
    
    <p>------------------------------------------------</p>
    
    
    
    <a href="#" target="_blank" id="my-link" onclick="javascript:Test('Test');">METHOD 2 - Expand version 2</a>
    
    
    <p>------------------------------------------------</p>
    
    
    <button onclick="myFunction()">METHOD 3 - Click Here to Expand/Unexpand All</button>
    
    <p>------------------------------------------------</p>
    
    
    <h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>
    
    
    
    <p>Open All :</p>
    <button class="collapsible">Open ALL Collapsible</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>OPEN ALL .</p>
    </div>
    
    
    <p>A Collapsible:</p>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 .</p>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    <p>Collapsible Set:</p>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 .</p>
    </div>
```

[image]

The goal is trying to configure one of the methods (hypertext or button) to trigger and open all collapsible sections instead of going to each one manually.

Thanks

Comment: Your code produces errors in the javascript console. You should deal with that and update your question.

Comment: Test and myFunction are not defined.

Comment: Hi Mike that's what I am trying to get some help on how to make it work.

Comment: Well, you already have a function that opens up a single one. Try seeing if you can add a click event listener to a single element that would loop through all of the `coll` elements and toggle the "active" class on all of them.